# How to get the ID of the user who sent the slash command in Discord.js V13

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Just had a simple question, I have some moderation slash commands on discord bot running on `Discord.js V13`, and I need to get the user ID of the person who runs the slash command. So I can then check for the permissions of the user on the guild to make sure he has the `Ban_Members` permission per example. And also how do I get the guild ID of where the slash command was executed

Thanks! If I wasn't clear feel free to ask me to clarify something

**The code I tried**

```
client.ws.on("INTERACTION_CREATE", async (interaction) => {
    if (interaction.data.component_type) return;
    const command = interaction.data.name.toLowerCase();
    const args = interaction.data.options;

    if (command == "mute") {
        const guildId = interaction.guildId;
        console.log(guildId);
        // client.api.interactions(interaction.id, interaction.token).callback.post({
        //  data: {
        //      type: 4,
        //      data: {
        //          embeds: [muteembed],
        //          ephemeral: "false",
        //      },
        //  },
        // });
    }
});
```

And I just receive `undefined` in the console log

**Something else I tried**

```
client.on("interactionCreate", async (interaction) => {
    if (interaction.data.component_type) return;
    const command = interaction.data.name.toLowerCase();
    const args = interaction.data.options;

    if (command == "mute") {
        const guildId = interaction.guildId;
        console.log(guildId);
        // client.api.interactions(interaction.id, interaction.token).callback.post({
        //  data: {
        //      type: 4,
        //      data: {
        //          embeds: [muteembed],
        //          ephemeral: "false",
        //      },
        //  },
        // });
    }
});
```

**And I get this error:**

```
if (interaction.data.component_type) return;
                             ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'component_type')
```

Comment: You can find all the available properties here: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Interaction

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros I tried many times, maybe i'm doing something wrong but I will edit my questions with the code I tried and what I received in console

Answer (score 1):

its usually

```js
interaction.user.id
interaction.member.id
```

Answer (score 0):

The two things you need is a user and a guild. Make sure you check there is a guild, otherwise things will go wrong.

```js
if(!interaction.guild) return; // Returns as there is no guild
var guild = interaction.guild.id;
var userID = interaction.user.id;
```